# Error Installing Silverstripe 4.0.1

Tags: silverstripe-4

Trying a fresh install of Silverstripe 4.0.1 but only gets this far -

```
Installing SilverStripe...

I am now running through the installation steps (this should take about 30 seconds)

If you receive a fatal error, refresh this page to continue the installation

Setting up /var/www/duonsdev/public_html/index.php
Setting up /var/www/duonsdev/public_html/mysite/_config.php
Setting up /var/www/duonsdev/public_html/mysite/_config/theme.yml
Setting up /var/www/duonsdev/public_html/.env
Setting up /var/www/duonsdev/public_html/.htaccess
Building database schema...
ERROR [Emergency]: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem::toIterable() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Filesystem\iterable, array returned IN POST /install.php Line 729 in /var/www/duonsdev/public_html/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php Source ====== 720: } 721: 722
```

And the error goes on and on. I tried refresh, but same error.

If I try a dev/build instead then it always dies at the point of -

```
Index File_Versions.OwnerID: created as index ("OwnerID")
Website Error
There has been an error

The website server has not been able to respond to your request
```

Trying to setup on Ubuntu 16 on local dev machine running Apache virtual host.
Never had this problem before and setup fine with ss4.0.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the module php version of apache in the same version as the cli php version.

Looks like the error was to do with the php version.
I was installing silverstripe through the cli using composer, but running a different version of php in apache.
So in the cli the php version was php 7.1
But in apache the php version was php 7.0.

After changing the apache php to match the cli (because silverstripe was installed using composer in the cli) it worked!

Comment: That was exactly my issue too - I ran 7.2 on CLI and 7.0 on fpm. You need to look for the path of your silverstripe-cache to identify this...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and after checking in the official [SilverStripe Community's slack channel](https://www.silverstripe.org/community/slack-signup), they mentioned this is because I was not running PHP 7.1.

Apparently, the official SilverStripe tarball offered in their website was built with PHP 7.1, so Composer added newer Symfony dependencies. They mentioned this would be fixed in newer releases.

Therefore, there are 2 ways you can fix this issue:

1. Download SilverStripe with Composer:

   ```
   $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
   $ ./composer.phar create-project silverstripe/installer /var/www/duonsdev/public_html/
   ```
2. Update your PHP version to 7.1.

After doing any of those steps, you will be able to access the web wizard for installing SilverStripe.

NOTE: If you're on a shared hosting, you will need to download SilverStripe on your local machine (ensuring the PHP version matches, at least in the major version, e.g. 7.0), and upload the files that were generated to your `public_html` directory.

Comment: If installing locally with a different PHP version, you can use composer's `platform` config option to specify the "live" php version: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform